# Using assign operator on already updated dataframe through method chaining

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like so:

```
pid  name    kids_count
10   tom     2
21   bill    0
22   peter   NaT
81   jen     4
20   jerry   1
```

I do the following method chaining to create an ID column but it takes two lines:

```
person_data = (person_data
                  .dropna()
                  .reset_index(drop = True)
                     )
person_data = (person_data
                  .assign(PKID = person_data.index + 1
                              ))
```

How can I method chain to create an ID column in one line of code? I essentially want to use the assign operator but pass the data frame thats already dropped NAs..

Pseudocode would look something like this, where the * is some code that takes in the person_data dataframe as dropping nulls:

```
person_data = (person_data
                  .dropna()
                  .reset_index(drop = True)
                  .assign(PKID = *)
                     )
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is not fully clear, but I assume:

```
person_data = person_data.assign(PKID=lambda d: d.dropna().index.to_series()+1)
```

Output:

```
   pid   name  kids_count  PKID
0   10    tom         2.0   1.0
1   21   bill         0.0   2.0
2   22  peter         NaN   NaN
3   81    jen         4.0   4.0
4   20  jerry         1.0   5.0
```

Or:

```
person_data = person_data.dropna().assign(PKID=lambda d: d.index+1)
```

Output:

```
   pid   name  kids_count  PKID
0   10    tom         2.0     1
1   21   bill         0.0     2
3   81    jen         4.0     4
4   20  jerry         1.0     5
```

Comment: I want to create the PKID after dropping Peter because he contains NA values. So the final dataframe would only have 4 rows

Answer (score 0):

Can you use:

```
person_data = (
    person_data.dropna()
    .assign(PKID=person_data.loc[df["kids_count"].notna()].index + 1)
    .reset_index(drop=True)
)
print(person_data)
```

Out:

```
   pid   name kids_count  PKID
0   10    tom          2     1
1   21   bill          0     2
2   81    jen          4     4
3   20  jerry          1     5
```